# Converge almost surely to zero with arbitrary $a_{nk}$

Tags: probability, probability-theory, probability-limit-theorems, law-of-large-numbers

Let $X_1,X_2,\dots,$ be i.i.d. random variables with $\mathbb{E}[X_1]=0,\operatorname{Var}(X_1)<\infty$. Assume that $\sum_{k=1}^{n}a_{nk}^2=\frac{1}{n}$, let $S_n=\sum_{k=1}^{n}a_{nk}X_k$, prove that

$$S_n\rightarrow0~~a.s.$$

It seems that this looks like the triangle array of some law of large numbers, we wish to use Borel-Cantelli to deal with this problem, but it seems hard since all $a_{nk}$ are arbitrary. How should we deal with the $a_{nk}$s here in this problem?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Note that the usual law of large numbers could look as a particular case of this result, namely, by taking $a_{n,i}=1/n$ for each $1\leqslant i\leqslant n$. But the SLLN  only requires $X_1$ to be integrable.

The difficulty here is that we cannot use maximal inequality because the weights may not depend on $n$ nicely.

But we can use a truncation argument: for a fixed $R$, let $X_{i,\leqslant R}:=X_i\mathbf{1}_{\{\lvert X_i\rvert\leqslant R\}}$ and $X_{i,\gt R}:=X_i\mathbf{1}_{\{\lvert X_i\rvert\gt R\}}$. Then
$$
\tag{1}
S_n=\sum_{i=1}^na_{n,i}\left(X_{i,\leqslant R}-\mathbb E\left[X_{i,\leqslant R}\right]\right)+\sum_{i=1}^n a_{n,i}\mathbb E\left[X_{i,\leqslant R}\right]+
\sum_{i=1}^na_{n,i}X_{i,\gt R}.$$
Observe that since $X_i$ is centered and has the same distribution as $X_1$,
$$
\sum_{i=1}^n a_{n,i}\mathbb E\left[X_{i,\leqslant R}\right]=-\sum_{i=1}^n a_{n,i}\mathbb E\left[X_{i,\gt R}\right]=-\sum_{i=1}^na_{n,i}\mathbb E\left[X_{1,\gt R}\right]
$$
hence by the Cauchy-Schwarz inequality, $$\tag{2}\left\lvert \sum_{i=1}^n a_{n,i}\mathbb E\left[X_{i,\leqslant R}\right]\right\rvert\leqslant \mathbb E\left[\lvert X_{1}\rvert \mathbf{1}_{\{\lvert X_1\rvert>R\}}\right].$$

An application of Cauchy-Schwarz inequality gives
$$\tag{3}
\left\lvert \sum_{i=1}^na_{n,i}X_{i,\gt R}\right\rvert\leqslant \sqrt{\sum_{i=1}^na_{n,i}^2\sum_{j=1}^nX_{j,>R}^2}=\sqrt{\frac 1n\sum_{j=1}^nX_{j,>R}^2}.
$$
The combination of (1), (2) and (3) with the strong law of large numbers applied to the i.i.d. integrable sequence $\left(X_{j,>R}^2\right)_{j\geqslant 1}$ give the almost sure inequality
$$\tag{4}
\limsup_{n\to\infty}\left\lvert S_n \right\rvert\leqslant 
\limsup_{n\to\infty}\left\lvert \sum_{i=1}^na_{n,i}\left(X_{i,\leqslant R}-\mathbb E\left[X_{i,\leqslant R}\right]\right)\right\rvert+\mathbb E\left[\lvert X_{1}\rvert \mathbf{1}_{\{\lvert X_1\rvert>R\}}\right]+\mathbb E\left[X_1^2\mathbf{1}_{\{\lvert X_1\rvert>R\}}\right]
$$
By [Hoeffding's inequality](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hoeffding%27s_inequality) , the following estimate takes place:
$$
\mathbb P\left(\left\lvert \sum_{i=1}^na_{n,i}\left(X_{i,\leqslant R}-\mathbb E\left[X_{i,\leqslant R}\right]\right)\right\rvert>\varepsilon\right)
\leqslant 2\exp\left(-\frac{\varepsilon^2}{4\sum_{i=1}^na_{n,i}^2}\right)
=  2\exp\left(-n\frac{\varepsilon^2}{4}\right).
$$
By the Borel-Cantelli lemma, the convergence
$$
\lim_{n\to\infty}\left\lvert \sum_{i=1}^na_{n,i}\left(X_{i,\leqslant R}-\mathbb E\left[X_{i,\leqslant R}\right]\right)\right\rvert=0
$$
takes place for each $R>0$  hence (4) gives
$$ 
\limsup_{n\to\infty}\left\lvert S_n \right\rvert\leqslant 
\mathbb E\left[\lvert X_{1}\rvert \mathbf{1}_{\{\lvert X_1\rvert>R\}}\right]+\mathbb E\left[X_1^2\mathbf{1}_{\{\lvert X_1\rvert>R\}}\right].
$$
Since $R$ is arbitrary, the conclusion follows by the monotone or dominated convergence theorem.